# Measuring angle before cutting?

Tags: wood, woodworking, lumber, angle

According to the instructions, I have to make a 21.5 degree cut in a 2x4 piece of lumber.

Here’s a screenshot of the instructions:
[image]

My question: can this measurement be done without having to buy a protractor or any other specialized tool?

Or even better, can I print out a protractor from the web?

Comment: Yes you can print a protractor from the Internet. Use a search engine to search the Internet for a printable Protractor.

Comment: Or use trigonometry and make some measurements. Your phone calculator will help if you turn it sideways ;-) Just be sure you are in degrees, not radians. Specifically, you want Tan (21.5°) which is 0.39391.

Comment: My table saw has a angle guide , not real accurate but to tell the truth a table saw with a good guide is about the only way you will get close for a rip cut on a 2x4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, you can of course do it with a [basic triangle calculator](https://www.calculator.net/right-triangle-calculator.html).

Do yourself a huge favor and buy a speed square. They are $10 and are useful for so many things beyond just marking an angle on a board.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the home depot here doesn’t have speed squares.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up buying one from Amazon. In the meantime I printed a protractor.